# Name conflicts with custom widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, naming

What is the best way to make custom widgets in Flutter that don't conflict with those exported by the material package? Specifically: I'm trying to make a design system based on [atomic design](https://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/). So, let's say I want my own `Text` and `Card` widgets. I can't name them `Text` or `Card` because both of these are exported by the material package.

Some options that I've considered:

1. **Creating a `ui` library and importing using `as`**

```dart
// components/atoms/Text.dart
import "package:flutter/material.dart" hide Text;
import "package:flutter/material.dart" as material show Text;

class Text extends StatelessWidget {
  Text(String content);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Imagine some more complicated styling specific to my design system
    return material.Text(content);
  }
}
```

```dart
// components/ui.dart
library ui

export "package:my_app/components/atoms/Text";
```

```dart
// screens/HomeScreen.dart

import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:my_app/components/ui" as ui;

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Example usage
    return ui.Text(content);
  }
}
```

This doesn't feel great... First, I need to remember to include `as` whenever I import the `ui` library, and second, it's slightly annoying to have to `hide` and `show` classes in my `Text` implementation.

2. **Just `hide` the conflicting classes**

```dart
// screens/HomeScreen.dart

import "package:flutter/material.dart" hide Text;
import "package:my_app/components/Text";

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Example usage
    return Text(content);
  }
}
```

Similar to option (1), I don't want to have to remember to `hide` all the classes that conflict with my custom widgets.

3. **Just use different names**

Maybe `AppText` or `ThemeText` or `UIText` or `AtomText`? This doesn't feel great either, especially for some of the other widgets like `IconButton`.

Is there a convention around this, or some decent solution? I haven't seen any custom UI libraries, but this is mostly useful for teams that want to reuse widgets across apps and keep a consistent style.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you want your custom Text class to do the exact same thing as a normal Text widget, but with a different design. If that really is the case, I propose that you change the ThemeData of your project. The `MaterialApp` widget takes a theme argument, so you can style your TextTheme, CardTheme, IconButtonTheme etc. in there. This would prevent any naming conflicts, save you a lot of coding, and makes it easy to tweak.

Things such as TextTheme allow for different types of styles, such as headlines, bodytext, etc., as described [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html).

Comment: Yeah, for the most part I've been using `ThemeData` which has been working. But it doesn't solve all the problems. For example: what if I want every `headline1` text to have some padding at the bottom? I guess I could make a `Headline` widget, but I was wondering what other options there may be.

Comment: I see. I am not very familiar with all the Text capabilities, but maybe the StrutStyle could be used for padding (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/StrutStyle-class.html). Otherwise you might be able to extend the Text class. I suppose Text is hardest to manipulate, so another option to consider is to change everything but the text: if you want padding underneath your text, then add padding to the top of widgets that appear below it - or just use SizedBox's. If anything, I don't think hiding conflicting widgets is a good idea, and i'd suggest to just use non-conflicting names

Answer (score -1):

1. You can add 'My' at the beginning of the widget, for example, 'MyText' instead of 'Text' and 'MyCard' instead of 'Card'.
2. You can use a tricky way, in my case I use an intentionally wrong dictation for naming. For instance, instead of 'Card' you can name 'Cart', or instead of 'Text', you can name tekst.